# Feedback requested: Global variables or classes in python2.7 countdown timer for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, global-variables

This is my first post to Stack Overflow. I started working with python 2.7 roughly 3 weeks ago and this is my first attempt at creating something in code (I have some basic experience with the Arduino IDE). Although the countdown timer now works for my purposes, I think I can make the code a lot better, especially where I keep declaring my global variable for color so that my digits appear to be flashing (red to black to red every second). I think I might need to use a class for color, but I don't know how. Would you have any tips for me?

This code is just bits and pieces collected and sewn together from code I found in online guides, mainly from this one: https://www.element14.com/community/community/code_exchange/blog/2012/12/17/raspberry-pi-workout-timer

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, especially on any beginner mistakes I might be making.

All the best,

Katrien

```
digit_colour = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)

# Colon between minutes and seconds
pygame.draw.rect(screen, digit_colour, pygame.Rect(left_offset + 2*(2*offset + digit_width), top_offset + offset + led_width / 2 - led_height, led_height, led_height))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, digit_colour, pygame.Rect(left_offset + 2*(2*offset + digit_width), top_offset + 3*offset + 3 * led_width / 2 - led_height, led_height, led_height))

print "Time is up!"

for j in range(0, timeIsUp):
     # Draw time on screen
     def colourChange():
        global digit_colour
        digit_colour = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)

     colourChange()          
     draw_time(screen, 0)
     pygame.display.flip()
     time.sleep(1)

    def colourChange():
        global digit_colour
        digit_colour = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)

     colourChange()          
     draw_time(screen, 0)
     pygame.display.flip()
     time.sleep(1)

 if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am new to and have experience with arduino IDE. You could've done a raw input asking you how long the countdown timer should last. And then you could have a loop with a minus -1 and a time.sleep(1) and a print of the  time left example

```
import time

minutes = raw_input("Minutes? ")
seconds = raw_input("Seconds? ")
time = minutes*60 + seconds
while(remaintime = True)
    time-1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(time," seconds left")
    if time<0
         remaintime = False
         print("time out")
```

This is a much simpler countdown clock but it works!

Comment: Thanks for this! I will try your code. It doesn't really answer my question about how to change the colours of the digits, though. Do you have any ideas of how I can make the blinking work more effectively?